# Images and styles do not load in GitLab

Tags: git, arch-linux, nginx, gitlab

I've installed gitlab on arch and now when I connect to it using localhost, everything displays fine If I use my domain, it works but displays no icons or images and the stylesheet is messed up

Comment: Please mention what you've tried and what didn't work in your question. Please show the HTML of the output that is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the error out, the nginx config was pointing to the wrong files

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what the exact config was and to which wrong files it pointed? For future visitors, that'd be more helpful..

Comment: Yeah I'd really like to know this as well, sadly I don't think they're coming back..

Comment: I also experienced gitlab not loading assets and the fix was reported here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/30197    (simply use port 80 when connecting!)